# iOS: What is this box/menu with a pointer/arrow called?

Tags: ios

On iOS, when we tap-hold some text, it displays a menu with an arrow in it pointing towards the text.

1. What is the name of that UI element?
2. How can I draw that on iOS/iPhone?

I tried all sorts of Google searches, but I could not find it.

See the dark grey element in the image below.

[image: example of UI element]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called a Popover control on iPad, on iPhone I think it does not come by default, but you can implement it using some 3-rd libraries, like:

https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController

Check out this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iykxemuxbk

and see the description that Apple may reject the app if you are using the standard one because it is made to use for the iPad by the iOS SDK.

But if you create your custom one for iPhone, I think it should be fine.